# Issue with button to toggle filter. MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC, and any help would be greatly appreciated. I currently have a page that displays a table of data. I would like to add a button that when clicked adds an additional filter to the page, and if clicked again will clear the filter (a toggle feature).

Below is a preview of the code I'm trying to use. I believe the view will work for what I want, but I am not sure about the controller.

View button:

```
   <td width="15%">
        @if (ViewBag.curStatus == "NotFiltered")
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Filter", "Index", new
       {
           sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,
           qryStatus = ""
       }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-xs" })
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Filter", "Index", new
       {
           sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,
           qryStatus = "Filtered"
       }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-xs" })
        }
    </td>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Table(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? 
              "invlocation" : "";
            ViewBag.curStatus = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? 
              "NotFiltered" : "Filtered";

        var samples = from s in db.Table1
                      select s;

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "NotFiltered":
                   string selectqry = "select * from Table1 where datereceived is null ";
                   selectqry = selectqry + " and submissionid not in (select id from Table2 where status='Done')";
                   break;
                case "Filtered":                   
                   selectqry = selectqry + " and status <> 'Pending'";
                   break;
            }

            List<vFiltered> list = db.Table1.SqlQuery(selectqry).ToList();

            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(vFiltered.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

Comment: Eh, there are a few concerns with this approach. Is this a legitimate project or a learning experience?

Comment: It is a project, but was given to me as a learning experience. Most of the HTML in the view was given to me.

As I'm sure you can tell the jumbled mess of code in the controller is mine. Compared to past experience MVC is odd to me.

It was preferred that I use a case with the SQL inside.

Comment: Additional thought: You aren't ever even making a SQL query from what I see. You are calling a string .ToList()

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to change that back when I uploaded this question. I changed it to SqlQuery(selectqry).

Comment: `string selectqry = "select * from Table1 where datereceived is null ";` should be moved to just before the switch, unless this won't even compile.

Comment: If `db` is a Entity Framework DbContext, you might want to look into building your query using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), which has the advantage of using LINQ to create your query using a strongly-typed model.

Comment: Is the only difference supposed to be that a filtered query should get `and status <> 'Pending'` added the query? If so, you actually wouldn't even need a switch.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, you've gotten me much closer by pointing out some obvious errors in my code.

Yes, that is what the button should filter out. However, I assumed it needed a switch for the option of clicking that same button a second time to remove the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I'd mention is that your MVC pattern is a little loose and there is far more code in the controller than I would opt for.

[image: MVC Pattern Diagram]

My preference and IMO a better approach is to move the logic into a business layer, or into a repository.

On the repository / Query:

```
string selectqry = "select * from Table1 where datereceived is null ";
```

Always happens, so it should be outside your if / case statements.

If you aren't using Entity Framework, and want to manually build the query then you could then do:

```
 switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "NotFiltered":
               selectqry = selectqry + " and submissionid not in (select id from Table2 where status='Done')";
               break;
            case "Filtered":                   
               selectqry = selectqry + " and status <> 'Pending'";
               break;
        }
```

Or slightly more cleanly:

```
Dictionary<string, string> filters = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{
    {"NotFiltered",  "and submissionid not in (select id from Table2 where status='Done')"},
    {"Filtered", " and status <> 'Pending'"}
}
```

and then:

```
string selectqry = "select * from Table1 where datereceived is null ";
selectqry += filters[sortOrder];
```

Although, why is a filter called sort order?

Better still, I'd ditch the sql string entirely, and setup the dbContext (assuming Entity Framework) and do something more like this:

```
 var results = dbContext.Table1;
if (sortOrder == "NotFiltered")
{
    results.where(x => !dbContext.Table2.Select(s => s.Id).Contains(x.Id);
}
else
{
    results.where(x => x.Status != "Pending");
}
return results.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me some great examples. I will mess around with some of these options.